# SwiftUI: Placing search bar always on top

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I wish to have search bar on top of the sheet always. I am using searchable and no matter what value I set "navigationBarDrawer" to, the search bar moves to top whenever I tap within it. I wish to have search bar statically placed such that it never moves, similar to search bar in bottom panel of Apple Maps.

How do I achieve it?

***Code:***

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine

@main
struct SampleAppApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SimpleTestData {
    let id = UUID()
    let score: Int
    let name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: .constant(true)) {
            ContentNewView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentNewView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""
    let searchTextPublisher = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                Color(red: 0.95, green: 0.95, blue: 0.97).ignoresSafeArea()
                
                VStack {
                    ResultsList(searchText: searchText, searchTextPublisher: searchTextPublisher)
                    .searchable(
                        text: $searchText,
                        placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always), 
                        prompt: "Search"
                    )
                    .onChange(of: searchText) { newText in
                        searchTextPublisher.send(newText) /// Publishes when a search term is changed. This is used to debounce the search.
                    }

                    Spacer()
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color(red: 0.95, green: 0.95, blue: 0.97))
            }
        }
        .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
        .interactiveDismissDisabled(true)
        .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)
        .onAppear {
            let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
            UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        }
    }
}

struct ResultsList: View {
    var searchText: String
    var searchTextPublisher: PassthroughSubject<String, Never>
    
    init(searchText: String, searchTextPublisher: PassthroughSubject<String, Never>) {
        self.searchText = searchText
        self.searchTextPublisher = searchTextPublisher
        UITableView.appearance().sectionFooterHeight = 0
    }
    
    let results = [
        SimpleTestData(score: 8, name: "Book1"),
        SimpleTestData(score: 5, name: "Book2"),
        SimpleTestData(score: 10, name: "Book3")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8.0) {
                if !results.isEmpty {
                    List {
                        Section(header: Text("Results")) {
                            ForEach(results, id: \.id) { result in
                                HStack {
                                    Text(result.name).font(.body)
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text("\(result.score)").font(.body)
                                }
                                .listRowBackground(Color.gray)
                                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Section(header: Text("Results")) {
                            ForEach(results, id: \.id) { result in
                                HStack {
                                    Text(result.name).font(.body)
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text("\(result.score)").font(.body)
                                }
                                .listRowBackground(Color.gray)
                                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 20.0)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, -20.0)
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it looks with current code.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I remember answering a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76832159/5133585). Perhaps the answers there help?

Comment: Ah I was fearing creating a custom search... anyways looks like that's what I will need and have to implement it. Thanks @Sweeper!